# SQL: select a count distinct for entries with higher ID than previous and conditions met

Tags: mysql, sql, count, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

Say that I have the following data in a table:

```
ID        ENTRY        NAME        ENTRY_ID
6         REMOVE       ALICE       333
5         ADD          JOHN        333
4         REMOVE       JOHN        222
3         ADD          ALICE       222
2         ADD          AMANDA      111
1         ADD          JOHN        111
```

I am trying to get a count for all who has an "ADD" in their latest entry which is determined by having a higher number in the "ENTRY_ID".

So in this case the count I am looking for is going to be 2, as "JOHN" in 333 has an "ADD" and "AMANDA" in 111 has an "ADD" - and none of the two has a higher ENTRY_ID with "REMOVE", as is the case with "ALICE", who is not suppose to be counted as her newest (highest) ENTRY_ID is a "REMOVE".

How can I most easily achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by name order by entry_id) rn
    from mytbale t
) t
where rn = 1 and entry = 'ADD'
```

Or using `first_value()`:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (
    select t.*, first_value(entry) over(partition by name order by entry_id desc) last_entry
    from mytbale t
) t
where last_entry = 'ADD'
```

This requires MySQL 8.0. In earlier versions, one option uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select count(*)
from mytable t
where 
    t.entry = 'ADD'
    and t.entry_id = (select max(t1.entry_id) from mytable t1 where t1.name = t.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list using aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having max(entry_id) = max(case when entry = 'ADD' then entry_id end);
```

This gets all names where the entry id of "ADD" matches the last entry id.

You can use a subquery and get the count:

```
select count(*)
from (select name
      from t
      group by name
      having max(entry_id) = max(case when entry = 'ADD' then entry_id end)
     ) t;
```

Otherwise, I might suggest a correlated subquery:

```
select count(*)
from t
where t.entry = 'ADD' and
      t.entry_id = (select max(t2.entry_id) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```